# codeiginter no direct access to functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I'm having this problem about direct access to functions: for example I have this code:

**controller users**

```
function index(){
//this is my users index view, user can add,edit,delete cars 
}

function details($id){
//a function where 1 car can be viewed in detail..

function add(){
//function to add car
}
```

Now if I go to address bar and type. localhost/myapp/users/detail it will go to the url and echo an error since $id is null. What I want is only the index is directly accessible if a user would type in the address bar. I don't want the users to go directly to myapp/users/add, etc..

Comment: Why not do a POST check on add()? Only POSTs are allowed, you can't do a GET on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI Controller functions *always* must be able to handle user input (i.e. url segments), which means anyone can type in whatever they wish and make a request. You can't stop that. The best practice is to either:

- Always provide default arguments
- Use the URI class to get your parameters, or `func_get_args()`
- Always validate the presence of *and* integrity of arguments passed to the controller, as you would with any other user input

Since it's much more common, accepted, and easier to read - just make sure to always provide defaults and **validate** them.

An example with your controller:

```
function index() {
    //this is my users index view
    //user can add,edit,delete cars
}

function details($id = NULL) {
    if ( ! $id) {
        // No ID present, maybe redirect without message
        redirect('users');
    }
    $user = $this->user_model->get($id);
    if ( ! $user) {
        // ID present but no user found, redirect with error message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'User not found');
        redirect('users');
    }
    // We found a user, load view here etc.
}

function add() {
    // Check for the presence of a $_POST value
    // You could also use the Form_validation lib here
    if ( ! $this->input->post('add_car')
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'Invalid request');
        redirect('users');
    }
    // Try to add the car here and always redirect from here
}
```

The only other way is to make the method private or use CI's `_underscore()` naming as suggested (making it inaccessible from the url). You can still call the function in other methods if you wish, as in:

```
function index() {
    if ($this->input->post('add_car')
    {
        // Call the private "_add" method 
        $this->_add();
    }
    // Load index view
}
```

So to make a long story short: You can't stop the requests from being made, you can only decide what to do when the request is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Add an underscore before the names of functions you want to hide:

```
function _details($id){
//a function where 1 car can be viewed in detail..
}
function add(){
//function to add car
}
```

Comment: if i do _details.. page will return 404 error. page not found.

Comment: sorry, there is no way around validating your inputs.

Comment: Yes, 404 is the error you get if you go to any URL that doesn't exist. When you use the underscore it prevents the function from being accessible by URL, so you get a 404. What would you want/expect to happen when you hide a function?